# How to create Alarm when container failed to mount efs for AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have requirement to create a alarm when ECS container failed to mount EFS endpoint.
Not sure what type of Metric should be used to handle this case.
For example for CPU Utilization AWS provide metric called CPUUtilization.

Is it possible to handle this mounting failed use case with AWS metric and alarm.

Comment: Did not tried it myself, but possibly there is EventBridge event fired when mounting fails, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html